# KNN IN r: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, knn

I´ve been studying the KNN algorithm to use in prediction of sentence(law), studying torought this link:

https://www.datascienceforlawyers.org/learning-resources/lesson-8/

where in this piece of code

```
model.knn <- knn(voting_pre1980[,-9], voting_post1980[,-9], voting_pre1980[,9], k = 3, prob=TRUE)
```

The 9 column have only two categories and works.

when i use my own data that have more categories(thats the only relevant difference that i found) in the target column, it trows the error:

> Error in knn(trein_1[, -6], trein_2[, -6], trein_1[, 6], k = 3, prob =
> TRUE) :    NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6) In addition:
> Warning messages: 1: In knn(trein_1[, -6], trein_2[, -6], trein_1[,
> 6], k = 3, prob = TRUE) :   NAs introduced by coercion 2: In
> knn(trein_1[, -6], trein_2[, -6], trein_1[, 6], k = 3, prob = TRUE) :
> NAs introduced by coercion

My data dont have Na, Nan or inf.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Can you `dput` sample data? most likely you have a few `factor` variables as columns for which `kNN` is not able to compute Euclidean distance.